# distinct xpaths in XML in database

Tags: xml, oracle

I have a XMLType column in table in oracle database.
Each row can have different set of XML tags in this column. Some tags can be present in one row and missing in other.
How can I find a superset of all possible XML paths, so that I dont miss out any values in this XML.
For the tags missing I will use NULL values.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: below example might add clarity to question: 
Consider these two rows in tables in XMLType column
<a> <b>1</b>Mc>2</c></a>
<a><b>1</b></a>
I want the paths as
/a/b 
as master set.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the number of possible XPaths is infinite; even the set of XPaths that select non-empty node sets is infinite. So I guess you need to qualify your question. I suspect you are interested in knowing all the paths using the child axis (only) that select at least one element. In XPath 2.0 (ignoring namespace issues) this is

```
distinct-values(//*/string-join(ancestor-or-self::node()/name(), '/'))
```